# Client Side Validation for ActiveModel Rails

Tags: validation, jquery-validate, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently using ActiveModel (no database attach to that model) for Ruby on Rails Project.

Is there any simple method to do client side form validation. I still cannot find useful one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not out of the box. Have you watched the relevant RailsCast? http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations

Comment: I got following error after i tried that tutorial................ wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)                                       <%= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>                         Any Idea Please?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062896/rails-client-side-validation-form-for-error

Comment: On homepage for that client-side-validation gem is written: "This library is no longer being maintained. Use at your own risk"